# how to round up and keep number of digits after decimal point in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, rounding

If .950 display .950
If .954 display .955
If .956 display .960

If the value of the thousandths place is between .001 and .004 then round up to .005

If the thousands place is between .006 and .009 then round to .010 and do not drop the zero.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you are right but in some cases the code you have found or written doesn't make any sense and it is better to simply post the problem instead of mis leading code. that is why I did not post any code even though I checked documentation at [developer.mozilla Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: In those cases it seems best to state that you found some code or documentation, give one or more links to some of what you found, and explain why that code or documentation is not suitable. Then we can be sure that you are not one of the lazy posters trying to get us to do their homework for them. I am glad that you are not one of those people. Why is it that the documentation that you linked to "doesn't make any sense"?

Comment: example "Decimal rounding" in the [mozilla documentation] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) does a standard rounding to nearest significant number while the problem is to always round toward higher number with difference of only 5 for the last decimal number

Answer (score 1):

Brutally:

```
function formatValue(value) {
    var tempVal = Math.trunc(value * 1000);
    var lastValue = (tempVal % 10);

    if (lastValue > 0 && lastValue <= 5) lastValue = 5;
    else if (lastValue > 5 && lastValue <= 9) lastValue = 10;
    else lastValue = 0;

    return parseFloat((Math.trunc(tempVal / 10) * 10 + lastValue) / 1000).toFixed(3);
}

formatValue(3.656); // -> "3.660"
formatValue(3.659); // -> "3.660"
formatValue(3.660); // -> "3.660"
formatValue(3.661); // -> "3.665"
formatValue(3.664); // -> "3.665"
formatValue(3.665); // -> "3.665"
```

**Pay attention**: function returns a string (`.toFixed` returns a string).. (but however a fixed decimal length doesn't have any sense in a number)

Answer (score 1):

Rounding to a certain number of decimals is done by multiplying the value to bring the desired amount of decimals into the integer range, then getting rid of the remaining decimals, then dividing by the same multiplier to make it decimal again.
Rounding to a "half-decimal" as you want is accomplished by doubling the multiplier (`2X` instead of `1X`).
The `+ 0.005` is to make it round up as desired, otherwise it would always round down.
`toFixed()` is used to make the string representation of the value have the decimal part padded with zeros as needed.

```js
function formatValue(value) { 
  return (Math.floor((value + 0.005) * 200) / 200).toFixed(3);
}

console.log(formatValue(1.950));
console.log(formatValue(1.954));
console.log(formatValue(1.956));
console.log(formatValue(1.003));
console.log(formatValue(1.007));
```